# Java app crash on MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) - KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE - EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Tags: java, crash, macos-monterey

We have multiple reports from users which have upgraded to `MacOS Monterey 12.0.1` with our `java application` with the following error:

```
Crashed Thread:        53  Java: Thread-13

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000104976000
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000104976000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

...

Thread 53 Crashed:: Java: Thread-13
0   ???                                 0x7ff8aefba940 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff81eaff112 __pthread_kill + 10
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff81ea81d10 abort + 123
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x11488a101 os::abort(bool) + 25
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x1149b24a2 VMError::report_and_die() + 2304
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x1145e5131 report_vm_error(char const*, int, char const*, char const*) + 84
6   libjvm.dylib                           0x1148e1ce8 SafepointSynchronize::block(JavaThread*) + 440
7   libjvm.dylib                           0x11496b006 JavaThread::check_safepoint_and_suspend_for_native_trans(JavaThread*) + 232
8   libjvm.dylib                           0x11456699e ThreadStateTransition::trans_from_native(JavaThreadState) + 150
9   libjvm.dylib                           0x114712a85 jni_DeleteGlobalRef + 53
10  libglass.dylib                         0x1679f79d1 -[GlassRunnable dealloc] + 49
11  Foundation                          0x7ff81f9aa10b -[_NSThreadPerformInfo dealloc] + 42
12  Foundation                          0x7ff81f976dc7 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 124
13  ???                                    0x116b9263c ???
14  ???                                    0x117b08640 ???
15  ???                                    0x5f8090931 ???
```

Any ideas on what could cause this and/or how to fix it?

Comment: same here for Monterey+, did you find any fix?

Comment: same here, meet crash when using pycharm.

Comment: try upgrading (Java)

Answer (score 0):

It works with the newest version of Java 8. But know we it need a license. Java 8 Update 202 I the last version without license.